# How would you add a table to Excel using Open XML?

Tags: openxml-sdk

The question is that of the subject. I have the following code, whose intention is to create the most simple table on Excel:

```
    Public Sub Crear_Tabla()
        Dim oTableDefinitionPart As TableDefinitionPart = o_WorkSheetPart.AddNewPart(Of TableDefinitionPart)("rId1")

        Dim oTable As Table = New Table() With {
            .Id = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(1),
            .Reference = StringValue.FromString("A1:B3"),
            .TotalsRowShown = False,
            .Name = "Tabla",
            .DisplayName = "Tabla"
        }

        Dim oTableColumns As TableColumns = New TableColumns
        For i As Integer = 1 To 2
            Dim oTableColumn As TableColumn
            oTableColumn = New TableColumn() With {
                .Id = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(i),
                .Name = StringValue.FromString("Columna" & i)
            }
            oTableColumns.Append(oTableColumn)
            i += 1
        Next

        Dim oTableStyleInfo As TableStyleInfo = New TableStyleInfo() With {
            .Name = "TableStyleMedium7",
            .ShowFirstColumn = False,
            .ShowLastColumn = False,
            .ShowRowStripes = True,
            .ShowColumnStripes = False
        }

        Dim oAutoFilter As AutoFilter = New AutoFilter() With {
            .Reference = "A1:B3"
        }

        oTable.Append(oAutoFilter)
        oTable.Append(oTableColumns)
        oTable.Append(oTableStyleInfo)
        oTableDefinitionPart.Table = oTable

        Dim oSheet As Sheet = o_Sheets.GetFirstChild(Of Sheet)
        Dim oTableParts As TableParts = New TableParts() With {.Count = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(1)}
        Dim oTablePart As TablePart = New TablePart() With {.Id = o_WorkSheetPart.GetIdOfPart(oTableDefinitionPart)}

    End Sub
```

But it doesn't appear to work, once I open the Excel book, it appears empty, even though the table is in the XML code. I have looked for it with the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool.

Many thanks in advance.